# structure If not work into method static Model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The following code retrieves a model from the database if the value passed as a parameter in the method is defined, however, it also implicitly ends up creating a new model.

What is the problem?.

```
public static function findOrCreateShoppingCartById($shopping_cart_id) {
  if($shopping_cart_id) {
    $cart = ShoppingCart::find($shopping_cart_id);
    return $cart;
  }
  $newCart = ShoppingCart::create();
  return $newCart;
}
```

Try to put exit; but still disrespect him

Can someone help me find the solution to the problem?
Thank you

Comment: what is the error or the problem?

Comment: the code looks fine.. maybe check if you are accidentally calling the function multiple times?